# Use the same domain for development and production environment - godaddy

Tags: iis, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-routing, web-hosting

I have an application that was written in ASP.Net Web API and angular JS.

I bought a domain in godaddy and have the website running normally @:

```
wwww.mydomain.com
```

I don't want to buy a new domain just for development purposes, so I was thinking in having:

`www.mydomain.com/dev` (only accessible with user and password).

I have created a virtual directory in the httphost/dev and deployed the files in there, but it seems I have problem with the Routes in `Web API`. It appears that they are using the same controller, and we would like to have two different controllers.

We are using `Dynamic Routes`, and the route table appears like this:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            // Web API configuration and services
            // Configure Web API to use only bearer token authentication.
            config.SuppressDefaultHostAuthentication();
            config.Filters.Add(new HostAuthenticationFilter(OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType));

            // Web API configuration and services

            var origins = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["corsAllowedDomains"];
            config.EnableCors(new EnableCorsAttribute(origins, "*", "*"));

            // Web API routes
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            config.EnsureInitialized();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );

            config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
            config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;

            // Remove default XML handler
            var matches = config.Formatters
                                .Where(f => f.SupportedMediaTypes
                                             .Where(m => m.MediaType.ToString() == "application/xml" ||
                                                         m.MediaType.ToString() == "text/xml")
                                             .Count() > 0)
                                .ToList();
            foreach (var match in matches)
                config.Formatters.Remove(match);
        }
    }
```

The website is hosted on Godaddy.

Comment: you should be able to create a `dev.mydomain.com` sub-domain. i think that's a better approach.

Comment: Hi @altej thanks for you idea. Goddady doesn't extra charge for a new subdomain. Now we have the subdomain like you said and is pointing to the same ip address of the website. Do you have any idea of how I can use this subdomain to execute a different controller ? thanks for the help.